# C# - System.FormatException: Invalid format string at System.DateTime

Tags: c#

I am Compairing the date formats and it works fine for `dd-MM-yyyy` input but throws exception for `dd/MM/yyyy`.

My Code:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string h = d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
if (h.Equals(s))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why you expect method called `ParseExact` to accept strings that don'g match exactly? And what result you expect instead? So far very unclear why you have this expectation after reading the documentation.

Comment: Have you considered using `DateTime.TryParse(datestring, out dateOut)`? It will accept strings formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` or `yyyy/mm/dd` or even `01/June/2017`

Comment: @Alexei I just figured that out sir. I was my fault was i didn't exactly knew what ParseExact does! Now I have got that. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnG Sir, yes I have now tried that way and got my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified that `DateTime.ParseExact` expects date only in `"dd-MM-yyyy"` format. Parsing any other format of date string will throw FormatException as it is specified in [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

> FormatException is thrown when *s* does not contain a date and time that
>   corresponds to the pattern specified in *format*.

If you want to support several formats, you should provide all of them. That is possible to do with [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts array of formats:

```
 var formats = new [] {"dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
 var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: thank you sir, that worked well for me. I was wrong in passing only a single format. Thank you sir that really helped.